# Increase signal voltage before Raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, relay, raspberry-pi, voltage-divider, logic-gates

Another newbie question.

I want to send a signal to a raspberry pi zero but I don’t have enough “signal-power”

I have a Adafruit Powerbooster 1000c. It basically takes power from a micro USB, a cellphone charger and charges a LiPo battery. Together with charger and LiPo battery it puts out 5v regardless if the charger is plugged in or not. When the battery is low the 1000c has a pin (LBO) that changes to 0v.

What I want is to send a signal to a Raspberry Pi when there is no power from the charger and the LBO is 0v.

I have used both Fritzing, which I know you all love, and gschem. I used Fritzing because it has symbols for both the Powerbooster 1000c and the Raspberry Pi Zero. This results that the schema from Fritzing has all the parts. I used gschem because it can generate a netlist for simulating with ngspice, which is not possible with Fritzing, as far as I know.

More on Adafruit Powerbooster 1000c, all this is copy-paste from Adafruit website:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465

PowerBoost 1000C is the perfect power supply for your portable project! With a built-in load-sharing battery charger circuit, you'll be able to keep your power-hungry project running even while recharging the battery! This little DC/DC boost converter module can be powered by any 3.7V LiIon/LiPoly battery, and convert the battery output to 5.2V DC for running your 5V projects.

Schema for 1000c
https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/24638

Control Pins
There's two 'control' pins.

- EN - this is the 'enable' pin. By default it is pulled 'high' to VS. To turn off the booster, connect this pin to ground. The switch can be as small as you like, it is just a signal. Contrast this to an inline power switch which would have to be able to handle up to 2A of current! When the chip is disabled the output is completely disconnected from the input.
- LBO - not a leveraged buy out! this is the Low Battery Output. By default it is pulled high to BAT but when the charger detects a low voltage (under 3.2V) the pin will drop down to 0V. You can use this to signal when its time to shut down or alert the user that the battery is low. There is also a red LED connected to this pin.

Some of you will question the selection of resistors and transistors. The selection is simply based on what I have at home. It makes it so much easier to try my contraption on the breadboard if I have all the components at home. If you feel that some of the components are very wrong, please let me know.

Here are the 2 schematics. I tried to make them look the same with components and comments at the same place.

[image: Fritzing version]
[image: gschem version]

Since gschem does not have symbols/componentc for Adafruits Powerboost 1000c and the USB, I drew a box around them and added comments.

- V_CHARGER represents the power from the cellphone charger.
- V_LBO represents the power provided from boosters pin LBO.
- V_BOOST represents the power from the bosters pin 5.0V

There is a box for an adhoc logical OR gate. Since I only want the signal sent to the raspberry pi when both charger and battery are “out of service” an OR statement seamed the way to go. Since I don’t have an OR gate in the form of an IC at home – I built it like this. Found an explanation at this site: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_3.html. I might have misunderstood the whole thing. Maybe, but not likely, the information on the site is wrong. Hopefully the hole OR gate I put together is OK and works.

There is another one box for a voltage divider. I wanted to have approximately the same voltage from the charger and the LBO going in to the logical OR gate described above.

The problem, as I see it, is that the power after the OR gate is not enough for the raspberry pi to recognize it as a HIGH. My first attempt was to have a relay. I only have 5v and 3v so  that wont work with only 2v  from the OR gate. I heard,read online, something about a transistor being able to work as an amplifier. Did not get that to work. Failed to use the transistor as a switch and as a relay. For a very short moment I taught about a pull-up resistor. I started reading about OP-AMP.

In a different, much simpler, project I have this python code. This reacts to buttons, ie it goes from LOW to HIGH.

```
GPIO.setup([redButton, blueButton], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(redButton, GPIO.FALLING, handle, bouncetime=1500)
GPIO.add_event_detect(blueButton, GPIO.FALLING, handle, bouncetime=1500)
```

In this project the raspberry pi will receive a constant HIGH and when there is no more power it will change to LOW. The code above will obviously need to be change to react from HIGH to LOW instead of LOW to HIGH.

I have tried to simulate with ngspice and no matter what I do I only get 3.1v at the most and 2.6v in worst case scenario.

Since I’m sure I have missed information that you need or made mistakes in my “design” I expect a lot of criticism, but please tell me what is wrong, why and how I can improve.

I was hoping to upload gschem file and simulation results but can't find any way to do so.

Comment: The premise of your question seems to be mistaken.  You have enough signal to feed the pi, the actual issue (if there is one) is that the signal voltage pulled up to VBat may be too high for the pi.  A simple FET operating as an open drain inverter with the ouptput pulled up to the pi's 3v3 would solve that so it's not really clear why you have such complex plans.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisStratton for you comment. Sadly I'm to much of a noob to know what a "A simple FET operating as an open drain inverter" means. Not a problem - sometime google is actually a friend. When it comes to my complex plans - I'm a noob and this was the only way I could figure out how to send the signal to the pi only when both the charger and battery is kaput. You say I have enough signal to feed the pi - All my simulation says that I might only get 2.6v. Is that enough? Anyway, thank you Chris, I'll start googling what a FET open drain is.